# To control battery at a certain capacity (for ex.20%) then the laptop will be automatically standby or hibernate for long-lasting the battery

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

I would like to control for setting my battery at a certain capacity (for ex.20%) then the laptop will be automatically standby or hibernate for long-lasting the battery.
Is there any solution, please?
Be noted: my Vostrol 3450, ubuntu 13.04, hibernate function is already rehabilitated.

The battery capacity I can find is in the file capacity as below:

```
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
```

I created the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

load=$(cat /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
min_load=20
if [ $load <= min_load ]; then
    pm-suspend
fi
```

On terminal, I perform the cli for test:

```
sudo /bin/battery-suspend
```

Then the result failed showing:

```
/bin/battery-suspend: line 5: =: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The battery capacity is stored somewhere in `/proc`. Possibly `/proc/acpi/battery` or something like that. You could write a bash script that reads the battery status and issues a hibernate or suspend command. It would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

load=$(cat /proc/acpi/battery)
min_load=20
if [ $load <= min_load ]; then
    pm-suspend
fi
```

I give no guarantee that this is right since I don't know how the output of `cat /proc/acpi/battery` looks like and I'm not that big of an bash script expert. Try it out and ask if you have any problems.

You could then create a cronjob that runs the script every minute or so. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) for cronjobs. You want to create your job as root user.

Comment: I tried to perform, but it's failed:       "cat: /proc/acpi/battery: No such file or directory", 
What can I do for next?

Comment: Like I said it's only possibly `/proc/acpi/battery`. Take a look into your `/proc` directory and try to find the file containing your battery status. There is really no default solution for this. You could use `acpi -V` (possibly install it first with `sudo apt-get install acpi`) but then you'd have to parse the output for the capacity.

Comment: What I can find described as above, hope it the right one. Could you help for creating a right bash script?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this script.

It raise a notification and then suspend your PC when battery level reach selected value.

```
#! /bin/bash

# read battery percentage value
OUT=`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep percentage`

# select only the int value
IFS=':' read -ra P <<< "$OUT"
PERCENTAGE="%"
BATTERY_VALUE=${P[1]%$PERCENTAGE}

# send a notification and then suspend pc
# if battery level is under 20%
if (( $BATTERY_VALUE  <= "20")); then
  notify-send "Battery Low level! Your PC will be suspended!"

  # play sound if you want to be alerted
  # paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga

  # wait for 3 seconds before suspend pc
  sleep 3
  # suspend your pc
  pm-suspend
fi
```

Copy this script into a bash file and move it into local bin folder:

```
sudo mv <script_file> /usr/local/bin/
```

Where *script_file* is the name (or path) of your script. Then you can use `cron` daemon to run it every 5 minutes (or select your execution frequency) to check battery level. So edit `cron` as superuser (script need super user permission to suspend PC):

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Select preferred editor and add at the end of file this line:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/<script_file>
```

Change *script_file* with your script name.

Now it should work. Check it after a system reboot.

I hope this will help you.